# About the relation $\tan^{-1} x= 2\tan^{-1}\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\frac\pi2$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

It is well known that 
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\tan^{-1}x+C \tag{1}$$

However, I integrated this differently and got an unusual result.

Suppose we make the substitution $x=\sinh\theta$ and $\mathrm{d}x=\cosh\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ so the integral becomes $$\int\frac{\cosh\theta}{\cosh^2\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\int\frac{1}{\cosh\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta \tag{2}$$

By the definition of $\cosh\theta$, we can rewrite this as $$\int\frac{2e^\theta}{e^{2\theta}+1}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=2\tan^{-1}e^\theta+C \tag{3}$$

Using the fact that $e^\theta=\cosh\theta+\sinh\theta$, we get $e^\theta=x+\sqrt{1+x^2}$, so the answer is then $$2\tan^{-1}\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)+C \tag{4}$$

Equating $(4)$ with $(1)$, we have $$2\tan^{-1}\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)+C=\tan^{-1}x \tag{5}$$

Plugging in $x=0$, we find $C=-\frac\pi2$. We now have the following strange relationship

> $$\tan^{-1} x= 2\tan^{-1}\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-\frac\pi2 \tag{$\star$}$$
>   This leads me to wonder: Why is this true geometrically, and does this relationship extend into the complex plane?

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function

Comment: This just looks false. When is this relationship suppose to hold? 

Let $x=1$ and evaluate this relationship.

Comment: @Mason : Or compute $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( \tan^{-1}x - 2 \tan^{-1}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and get $0$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The geometric interpretation could be found in the figure below.

We have $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x , ~\beta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)$, and $\alpha = 2 \beta$.

Combining these three equations would lead to your results.

[image]

For a formal proof, let $\theta = \arctan \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)$. Since

$$ x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} \geq \sqrt{1 + x^2} - |x| > 0,$$

we have $\theta \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Also, note that

$$
\begin{align}
\tan\left(2\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)&= -\frac{1}{\tan(2\theta)}\\
&= -\frac{1 - \tan^2 \theta}{2 \tan \theta}\\
&= -\frac{1 - \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)^2}{2 \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)}\\
&= x.
\end{align}
$$
As $\left(2\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, i.e., $\left(2\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ lies in the range of $\arctan(\cdot)$, we know that
$$ \arctan x = 2\theta - \frac{\pi}{2} = 2\arctan \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right) - \frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Comment: Can we pin down exactly when this holds?

Comment: A formal proof could be done by using the formula of $\tan(2 \theta)$, but need to consider the range of $\arctan$.

Comment: Very nice geometry. See my answer using the arctan addition formula.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)
=\arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})
$
with $k\pi$
thrown in as needed,

$\begin{array}\\
\arctan x- 2\arctan\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)
&=\arctan x- \arctan\left(\frac{2x+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1-(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}\right)\\
&=\arctan x- \arctan\left(\frac{2x+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1-(x^2+2x\sqrt{1+x^2}+1+x^2)}\right)\\
&=\arctan x- \arctan\left(\frac{2x+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1-(2x^2+2x\sqrt{1+x^2}+1)}\right)\\
&=\arctan x- \arctan\left(\frac{2x+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{-(2x^2+2x\sqrt{1+x^2})}\right)\\
&=\arctan x- \arctan\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{-x(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}\right)\\
&=\arctan x- \arctan\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right)\\
&=\arctan x+ \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
&=\arctan\left(\frac{x+\frac1{x}}{1-x\frac1{x}}\right)\\
&=\arctan\left(\frac{x+\frac1{x}}{0}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

We need to be very careful with [principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) ,

Let arccot$(x)=2y\implies x=\cot2y$ and $0<2y<\pi$

$x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=\dfrac{\cos2y+1}{\sin2y}=\cot y$ as $y\ne\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies2\tan^{-1}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})=2\left(\dfrac\pi2-\cot^{-1}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\right)=\pi-2y$

and $\tan^{-1}x=\dfrac\pi2-\cot^{-1}x=\dfrac\pi2-2y$