# Two different answers from integrating $\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ in two ways. What did I do wrong?

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the answer of the integral $$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$ I use the substitution $x=\cosh(t)$ ($t \ge 0$) which yields $dx=\sinh(t)\,dt$. By using the fact that $\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1$ we can write $x^2-1=\cosh^2(t)-1=\sinh^2(t)$. Since $t\ge 0$, $\sinh(t)\ge 0$, and we have $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sinh(t)$. Now, by substituting for $x$, $dx$, and $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ in the first integral, we have 
$$\int\frac{dt}{\cosh(t)}$$
Since $\cosh(t)=(e^t+e^{-t})/2$ by substituting this in this integral we have 
$$2\int\frac{dt}{e^t+e^{-t}}.$$ 
Now by multiplying numerator and denominator in $e^t$ one can write:$$2\int\frac{e^t\,dt}{1+e^{2t}}$$ 
Now by using $z=e^t$ in this integral one can write ($dz=e^t\,dt$): $$2\int\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$$ 
So we have $$\int\frac{dt}{\cosh(t)}=2\arctan(z)=2\arctan(e^t)$$ 
On the other hand $$t=\cosh^{-1}(x)=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$$ 
So we have $$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int\frac{dt}{\cosh(t)}=2\arctan(\exp(\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})))$$
which yields

> $$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=2\arctan(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

but this answer is wrong. The true answer can be obtained by direct substitution $u=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and is

> $$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\arctan(\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

I don't want to know the answer of the integral. I want to know what I did wrong? Can somebody help?

Answer (score 6):

The constant! You can't forget the constant!

$$2\arctan(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}) = \arctan(\sqrt{x^2-1}) + \frac{\pi}{2}$$ for $x \ge1$ and
$$2\arctan(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}) = \arctan(\sqrt{x^2-1}) - \frac{\pi}{2}$$ for $x\le1$ (Have a go at proving these statements)

As the solutions differ by a constant, there is no contradiction; both of your solutions are correct.

EDIT:

See [this similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761206/about-the-relation-tan-1-x-2-tan-1-leftx-sqrt1x2-right-frac-pi2?rq=1) for a hint on how to go about proving the identity (although the post in question deals with a different one).

Comment: thank you sir .

Answer (score 1):

Verify by differentiation.

$$(2\arctan(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}))'=2\frac{1+\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^2+1}=2\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{2(x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-1)}\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

and

$$(\arctan\sqrt{x^2-1})'=\frac{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{(\sqrt{x^2-1})^2+1}.$$

Hence both answers are correct.